# Shell Substitution Precedence

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I get tripped up on the sequence of substitutions shell does.  I understand shell will do variable substitution before file substitution, which is done before the command line is parsed.  Shell can do many different substitutions.  I just don't know which is done first, second, third, and so forth.  Does anyone have a precedence chart of shell substitutions?

Answer (score 4):

From man (1) bash:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde  expansion,  parameter,  variable  and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Comment: Although the question doesn't mention `bash`, this holds for the POSIX shell as well (ignoring brace expansion, which is not part of the POSIX standard).

Comment: And the link: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions